# Valid Directoryname on Android

Tags: android, regex, file

I search for a regex pattern to check the name of a new directory before i create it on the file system.
For example is "/" not allowed in the name of a directory.
I have no experience in regex so any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\\w+
```

- \w is equilvalent to [A-Za-z0-9_]
- "+" will match one or more chars

To

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) the documentation.

Edit

```
  Log.e("TAG", "Helloworld " + "helloworld\\".matches(("\\w+")));
```

last one returned false for me.

Comment: I got a "Invalid escape sequence" error if i use this answer. What make i wrong? ["Hello".matches( "/^\w+$/" )]

Comment: this is valid but not what i want. I allow each word and number but no / and now additional .